# How to insert date selected separately into mysql using Java(JSP)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

In my project I want to save date which is read separately as day,month,year by using a select box. The code used is

```
<%
     String value=null;
     String[] h=null;
      h=request.getParameterValues("qns[]");
     String expert=request.getParameter("expert");
     int sday=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sday"));
     int smonth=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("smonth"));
     int syear=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("syear"));
     int eday=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("eday"));
     int emonth=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emonth"));
     int eyear=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("eyear"));
     String start=syear+"-"+smonth+"-"+sday;
     String end=eyear+"-"+emonth+"-"+eday;    
   for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++)
      {
          s.savetask(h[1],expert,start,end);
      }
   %>
```

The savetask function is

```
  public int savetask(String qnid,String userid,String start,String end)
  {
     int n=0;
     try{

         String sql="insert into task(user_id,question_id,start_date,end_date,status)values('"+qnid+"','"+userid+"','"+start+"','"+end+"',0";
         n = db.modifyingQueries(sql);
     }
     catch(Exception e){

     }
     return n;
 }
```

But it is not inserting values to  the table `task`
The table format for task is

```
task_id      int (Auto increment)
user_id      int
question_id  int
start_date   date 
end_date     date
status       int
```

Comment: What is it doing instead? In your catch block add a `e.printStackTrace()` so we know what's going on.

Comment: Any errors/exceptions in console ???

Comment: Never swallow exceptions. If an exception is happening, the very minimum you want is to log it someplace where you can read it to find what is happenning.

Comment: Are you getting an error - if so, what is the error. And what is the table structure for 'task'

Comment: do write `catch(Exception e){ e.printStacktrace()}`,and do the job again,Now an exception prints in console,Update the post with that exception message.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis,@SURESH ATTA,@aquaraga There is no error but the value is not inserting

Comment: @Salini There's no error because you are swallowing it by not logging it. Make the changes we are asking for.

Comment: What we are telling is,when exception occurs,You are saying do not show it console.see my line above,in your catch block write `e.printStacktrace()`,then the errors shows to you.

Comment: ya I have changed but still there does not showing any error message

Comment: I found one mistake in your query please try with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Your sql line is invalid.Missing bracket in the end.

```
   String sql="insert into task(user_id,question_id,start_date,end_date,status)values
                            ('"+qnid+"','"+userid+"','"+start+"','"+end+"',0");
                                                                            ^
```

one more syntax error is there is no need for `"`  after the `0`  in the end since it is an `int`(realized after you updated the column structure).

Still if you face further exceptions,provide the stack trace.

Update(comment  that helpful to resolve the issue):

What you have to do is after the line `String sql = ...`,Put `System.out.println(sql)` So it prints the `query` in console.Pick that line and fire it on your Data base query manager.And see for any syntax errors.

Comment: Salini,not working is always a wrong description of problem.Did you find any stack trace ??Are you sure that,there is nothing printed in console ?

Comment: I think the error is on the date format. And I dont know much about it

Comment: What you have to do is after the line `String sql = ...`,Put `System.out.println(sql)`  So it prints the query in console.Pick that line and fire it on your Data base query manager.And see for any syntax errors. ??got it ?

Comment: @Salini  :)  OK. Glad to help you out. Please mark it as answer if you found this helpful.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA, does a comment can mark as an answer? I have voted for that comment but I didnt found any link to set it as an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36434/discussion-between-ss--and-salini)